# My getters are giving me a nonstandard and cannot convert error

Tags: c++, constants, getter

I'm learning as I'm going but while writing these getters for a stat page for a character, I'm getting an error that it is nonstandard, it cant convert the const, and it  tells me to add a & "to create a pointer to a member"

I have tried making them pointers with *, I have tried not making them const, making them public, adding any headers that my be missing.

These are the only lines of many that are giving the errors.  It produces about 30 errors.

```
inline const double& getX() const { return this->getX; }
inline const double& getY() const { return this->getY; }
inline const std::string& getName() const { return this->name; }
inline const int& getLevel() const { return this->level; }
inline const int& GetExpNext() const { return this->expNext; }
inline const int& getHP() const { return this->hp; }
inline const int& getStamina() const { return this->stamina; }
inline const int& getDamageMin() const { return this->getDamageMin; }
inline const int& getDamageMax() const { return this->getDamageMax; }
inline const int& getDefense() const { return this->getDefense; }
```

These are some of the repeating errors.

```
Error   C3867   'Player::getX': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const double &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const double &'
Error   C3867   'Player::getY': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const double &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const double &'
Error   C3867   'Player::getDamageMin': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const int &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const int &' 
Error   C3867   'Player::getDamageMax': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const int &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const int &' 
Error   C3867   'Player::getDefense': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const int &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const int &'
Error   C3867   'Player::getX': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
Error   C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const double &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const double &'
Error   C3867   'Player::getY': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: I suspect that the member variables in question do not have names that start with "get".

Comment: Surely your actual member variables are not named `getX` and such, but rather `x`? Made a typo while creating your getters?

Comment: On a side note, returning primitives such as `int` and `double` by const reference is a pessimisation.

Comment: All that explicit `this` dereferencing (`this->`) is redundant.

Comment: Post the entire header file code where we can see the variable and  function declaration

Comment: To be more explicit regarding the error message: in `getX`, `getX` is the name of the function you're defining, so the compiler thinks that you're trying to return a pointer to the function itself. And member functions don't implicitly convert to member function pointers.

Comment: Off-topic: Coordinates as double? Your stats look like for some kind of game, and in such a case, I'd prefer integrals - such like uint32_t (or int32_t, if origin is in center of the map) - or if the map is large enough, (u)int64_t (need to `#include <cstdint>` for these types).

Comment: Off-topic again: Do you have another member for current experience (that's what I'd usually expect from games)? Then `expNext` (the member *variable*) should be redundant, you should be able to calculate it from level and current experience. Be aware that such redundancies can easily get a source of bugs if you don't code carefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just explaining the errors in more detail, as the true answer already is [given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56232816/1312382); you are getting two of these for the same issue:

```
inline const double& getX() const { return this->getX; }
//                     ^                           ^ (!)
```

Have you noticed that the two identifiers are the same? At the time you are trying to return `getX`, the function is already declared and known. And you now are trying to return exactly this function.

> ```
> Error C3867 'Player::getX': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
> ```

With member functions, you can do two things: Either call them or get their address to form a member function pointer. Unlike free-standing functions and static member functions, non-static member functions are not converted automatically to pointers; for these, you need to explicitly specify the address-of operator `&`:

```
void f() { }
class C { public: void f() { } };

void (*pf0)() = &f;        // explicitly taking address
void (*pf1)() = f;         // works for free standing functions
void (C::*pf0)() = &C::f  // ONLY can explicitly take address
//void (C::*pf1)() = C::f // gives you the error you saw already
```

Well, syntax for function pointers, especially member FP, is really uggly. Usually you are better off defining aliases (`typedef` or `using`) or, in above case, you could have used `auto`.

> ```
> Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'const double &(__thiscall Player::* )(void) const' to 'const double &'
> ```

Assuming you already fixed the first error (by adding the required `&`), then you have a type mismatch between what you declared as return type and what you actually are returning; the former a reference to double, the latter a member function pointer. So you can either adjust the return value (impossible in this case: you'd have to return a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to ...) or select the correct member as shown already.

If you wonder about `__thiscall`: It just is the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), which we usually don't have to specify explicitly (unless we need a non-default one – which usually is the case if e. g. coding against WinAPI).

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to be sure because you've written only posted the lines with the errors instead of posting all the relevant code. but it seems you have written code like this

```
class Player
{
public:
    inline const double& getX() const { return this->getX; }
private:
    double x;
};
```

when you should have written code like this

```
class Player
{
public:
    inline const double& getX() const { return this->x; }
private:
    double x;
};
```

Note `x` not `getX`.

And then as has already been pointed out in the comments, `inline`, `this` and use of references are all redundant or bad in this case. So you can write the even simpler

```
class Player
{
public:
    double getX() const { return x; }
private:
    double x;
};
```

Comment: Wow, well.  That was it, I was mislabeling them,  and I understand why it wasn't working.  Thanks everyone for the quick reply. I'm really glad it was such a simple mix up.